# (C#) How do you deal with a Base class with a constructor, when you want to make an inheriting class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, base-class

Im trying to make a Dog class, inheriting the Animal base class which has a constructor. Is there any way I can make the class Dog : Animal, but somehow use the Animal constructor with it? I looked at the similar questions, but I didnt get the answer I'm looking for.

```
class Class1
{       
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Animal animal = new Animal("Spotty", 5, 4);
        animal.Print();
   }
}

class Animal
{
    public string animalName;
    public int animalAge;
    public int animalLegs;
    public Animal(string name, int age, int legs)
    {
        animalName = name;
        animalAge = age;
        animalLegs = legs;       
    }       

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " +animalName);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: "+ animalAge);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Legs: " +animalLegs);
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    //This wont work; there will be an error
}
```

Comment: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235): *A constructor can use the `base` keyword to call the constructor of a base class.*

Comment: `Animal.animalLegs` and so forth is quite redundant (a `tautology`).  I would expect an animal to have no other kind of legs other than animallegs.  Take your cues from the NET framework all around you where it is `Rectangle.Width` not `Rectangle.RectangleWidth`.  Same for that casing

Answer (score 2):

You should either add a default constructor to `Animal`, or add the necessary constructor to `Dog`:

```
public Dog(string name, int age) : base(name, age, 4)
{
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be nitpicky, but... why Dog ctor have "legs" arg? I don't know if you understand me...